# Negative estimator value in mixed effects model when positive is expected

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I ran a mixed effects model analysis in Rlme4 and I'm confused by the output, visual inspection of the data shows that upward transitions are associated with higher values of the DV (movement error) and downward values associated with lower values of the DV. However, the output has negative estimator values for both upward and downward (see below). The intercept is the value for a baseline recording that has relatively high levels of movement error.

table of results below (sorry for the format of this, I couldn't get the table to show properly)

```
                            Movement error
```

Predictors// Estimates     // CI          //     p

(Intercept)      //    199.65. // 167.22 – 232.08 // <0.001

speed     //    3.87      //   3.16 – 4.59    //  <0.001

Downward transitions // -5.46     //  -17.05 – 6.12   //  0.355

Upward transitions. // -27.07   //   -42.47 – -11.67  // 0.001

type         //  11.42    //    2.78 – 20.06    //  0.010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing usually happens because there is a different asociation of the outcome with one or more covariates in the population (between groups), than in groups (within groups). When these associations are of a different sign, you get this result. It is an example of simpson's paradox. One way to get further insight is to fit contextual effects, where you mean-centre the covariates within groups, and then include the group means in the model. This seperates out the within-group and the between-group effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it's very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. If you search this site for Simpson's Paradox and Mixed Model you should find some more detail.